# Perl wide characters (Mechanize get / mkdir fails)

Tags: perl, mechanize

I'm currently writing a small perl script to scrape certain pages in which there is asian characters (chinese both simplified and traditional). The first problem I face is that, when using Mechanize the string's I'm getting from the 'source' contain wide characters. The source page is encoded in utf-8 already. The following are the options and packages I'm using:

```
use strict ;
use warnings ;
use utf8;
use Encode qw(decode encode);
use File::Path qw(make_path remove_tree);
binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");
use Win32::Unicode::Dir;
```

I can print the string without any issues. But when I try to make a directory mkdir complains of wide characters or invalid arguments. I've since tried a workaround with Win32::Unicode package using mkdirW. The directory is now creating successfully, but I'm unable to use the directory when calling:

```
$mech->get( $url, ':content_file' => $savePath) or die $!;
```

The get command completes successfully, but the directory of $savepath is left empty. This method works when there are normal alphanumeric characters involved.

Example of the folder title would be: 蜂蜜 Honey
So

```
my $savePath = "C:\\" . $title . "\\Picture_of_honey.jpg";
where $title = "蜂蜜 Honey";
```

I just can't get it to make the directory and save the file. It has to be an encoding issue, but I've tried to encode to utf 8 but that garbles the original text since its already encoded in utf8. Decoding gives me a wide character error.

Answer (score 0):

When you use Win32::Unicode::Dir, it does not override the buggy Perl built-in `open` etc. in other packages like LWP::UserAgent. Just use the `:content_cb` callback to write into a file yourself.

It's likely not a good idea to let external Web sites that are not under your control determine the file name on your system. This is an annoyance at best (many characters are illegal on Windows file systems), or a security flaw at worst. Don't fall into that trap and store the document title separately (in a database/file), and give the content documents a safe filename that your code generated.

Comment: How would I go about safely converting the web sites characters into Windows safe characters? So you're saying I should parse out all the foreign text and just store it in a file instead of creating the directory with that. 

Could you elaborate on how to fix this annoyance. I'm not really concerned about security at the moment.